# Which should I repair first?

Tags: flooring

[image]

[image]

There is a gap between the baseboard and the vinyl floor, and parts of the floor have holes.

Does it matter which I repair first?

Comment: Baseboard is just trim to hide not perfect meeting of wall and floor.  It is placed last.  The edit button has an icon looking like mountains and sun for pictures, or use imgur/similar and add a link.

Comment: Easiest way to add photos is with the 'mountains' icon at the top of the edit box. That handles the unnecessarily ugly syntax details for you, as well as handling uploading if desired.

Comment: Fixed the image syntax. Yes, all those brackets really are needed. Don't ask why.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend removing the baseboard, repairing the flooring, and reattaching or replacing--depending on your plans there--the baseboard.

Answer (score 0):

Re baseboard: Looks like there was originally carpet, which the baseboard was installed in top of to hide the carpet's edge. The gap left by the carpet's removal is mostly harmless.

If it bothers you it is possible (though annoying fiddly work) to pry the baseboards free and install them again flush to the floor. You will probably  have to do some repainting after doing so.

Or, easier, just install a strip of quarter-round or cove molding over that gap as a "shoe", painting it to match the existing molding. Be careful not to get paint on the floor; if nervous  you might want to consider painting the molding (and letting it dry), *then* nailing it in place.

In fact the bulge at the bottom of the baseboard looks like exactly this sort of shoe molding, just tacked on at carpet height rather than floor height. I'd probably apply a new one go over it rather than trying to replace it, due to the paint gluing it in place.

Personally, I wouldn't bother. Nobody but you is ever likely to notice.